# Permance compare between Numpy and python built-in list append function

Tags: list, numpy, loops, append

I am trying to compare the performance between numpy multiplex and some old school loop way with list.append way, since I was told the numpy is much faster than the loop.
I have test it multiple times, but seems the calculation time is pretty much the same, sometimes list.append even faster, am I overlooked something?

use numpy the time cost 0.02194070816040039
not use numpy the time cost 0.012960195541381836

the code I used is as following

```
import numpy as np
import time

n = 10000
time1 = time.time()
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
for i in range(n):
    z =2*y
time2 = time.time()
print("use numpy the time cost {}".format(time2-time1))

time3 = time.time()
y1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
z=[]
for i in range(n):
    for item in y1:
        z.append(2*item)
time4 = time.time()
print("not use numpy the time cost {}".format(time4-time3))
```

Comment: Take `y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])` out of the timing loop if you want to see the real array speed.  Making an array from a list is relatively slow.  If starting with lists it is often faster to stick with them.

Comment: You should use much larger input in order to get a half decent measurement.

Comment: Hi Hpaulj, Thanks for the comment, but usually for the metric O calculation, everything outside loop will be ingnored. and I also tried to the init of array part out of the time calculation, and got the same result :)